# Below is the code for implementing a Queue using an array without using a counter for number of elements in it. Can someone please explain it to me?

Tags: java, data-structures, queue, implementation

I've been trying to understand the code given below for a while. This is to implement Queue using array but without counting the elements inside the queue while inserting and deleting i.e. just by using rear and front indexes. Idea behind this was to increment the size of array by 1 so that the conditions for "isFull()" and "isEmpty()" are not the same.

I want to know how adding 1 extra index is solving the problem of differentiating between full and empty. These methods don't make sense to me.

```
public class QueueWo {

    private int maxSize;
    private long[] arr;
    private int rear;
    private int front;

    public QueueWo(int s) {
        maxSize = s + 1;
        arr = new long[maxSize];
        rear = -1;
        front = 0;
    }

    public void insert(long j) {
        if(rear == maxSize - 1)
            rear = -1;
        arr[++rear] = j;
    }

    public long remove() {
        long temp = arr[front++];
        if(front == maxSize)
            front = 0;
        return temp;
    }

    public long peek() {
        return arr[front];
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return rear + 1 == front || front + maxSize - 1 == rear;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return rear + 2 == front || front + maxSize - 2 == rear;
    }

    public int size() {
        if(rear >= front)
            return rear - front + 1;
        else
            return (maxSize - front) + (rear + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into the term _ring buffer_.

Comment: what do you want ?

Comment: I want to know how adding one extra index solves the problem of not having the same conditions for Empty and Full. These conditions to now make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

You create a fixed size array and start putting elements in it. Once you reach the end by queuing elements, you start from the start of array and so on in a circular manner. While doing this, your front keeps moving one index ahead on each remove and on reaching the end, starts from the beginning.

Comment: But why do we add and subtract 2 in isFull() and 1 in isEmpty()?

Comment: I dont think those method are correct.. whats the source of your class ?